# Automator simulation of the mouse and keyboard

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, automator

My problem: "watch me do" in automator only recognizes for cocoa buttons and doesn't work for apps like games with interfaces drawn my rendering engines.

Desired solution: an Automator action(s) that simulate mouse movements and clicks to coordinates on screen. "Automator Virtual Input" is a great app but doesn't is far outdated (doesn't work in lion)

And considering the amount of scripts i need to create, applescript isn't a time effective solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you're trying to push Automator past the practical limits of the tool. Instead, a macro program such as [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) or [iKey](http://plumamazing.com/mac/ikey) are better choices, albeit not free.

Comment: i tried keyboard maestro but it lacks a click and hold =/

Comment: Apparently iKey can do that. See http://bit.ly/p7gVhu

Comment: not loving the crashing of that app tbh =/

Comment: Contact iKey's developer with your problem. You'll find him to be quite responsive.

Comment: Anyone know of any free/open-source applications similar to those listed here so far?

Answer (score 4):

You can automate a mouse click using Applescript.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Application_Name"
        key code 53
        delay 1
        click (click at {1800, 1200})
    end tell
end tell
```

---

If you want to click within a browser window you can use Applescript with the help of Javascript

```
tell application "safari"
    activate
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('element').click();"
end tell
```

---

Purely via terminal, you can create a textfile with the name `click.m` or whatever name you like, save it with the following code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSUserDefaults *args = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    int x = [args integerForKey:@"x"];
    int y = [args integerForKey:@"y"];

    CGPoint pt;
    pt.x = x;
    pt.y = y;

    CGPostMouseEvent( pt, 1, 1, 1 );
    CGPostMouseEvent( pt, 1, 1, 0 );

    [pool release];
    return 0;
}
```

then compile it:

```
gcc -o click click.m -framework ApplicationServices -framework Foundation
```

and move it to the appropriate system folder

```
sudo mv click /usr/bin
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/click
```

and now you can run a simple terminal command to manipulate the mouse

```
click -x [coord] -y [coord]
```

---

Other scripts you could use include [MouseTools](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html) or [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/); both of which are open-source.

Answer (score 0):

[QuicKeys 4](http://startly.com/products/quickeys/mac/4/) provides the functionality your looking for.  They offer a free trial version as well as a paid version.  The free version has all the same features as the paid version, only it nags you that it is a trial.

QuicKeys, however, has not been updated in several years & has issues since Mountain Lion.
Some parts work, others fail; so I'd recommend a thorough test.

Comment: Can you please add a link to Quickeys? It is always helpful to add a link to what you mention so that the OP can find the right piece of software.