# Executable only works in specific folders

Tags: macos, command-line

I have some executable files that I run in the terminal, and I noticed that they only work if they are on the Desktop or in the Applications folder.

One example is [this small script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/154180). When I compile `click.m`, the output executable only runs if they are inside the folders mentioned above.

I could move the files, but while I am developing the script, what could I do to run them from a different folder?

Edit:

### Steps to reproduce:

Create a file named click.m on the desktop with the following contents:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

void doubleClick(CGPoint point);
void singleClick(CGPoint point);
void rightClick(CGPoint point);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSUserDefaults *args = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    int x = [args integerForKey:@"x"];
    int y = [args integerForKey:@"y"];

    CGPoint pt;
    pt.x = x;
    pt.y = y;

    CGEventRef a = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, kCGEventLeftMouseDown, pt, kCGMouseButtonLeft);
    CGEventRef b = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, kCGEventLeftMouseUp, pt, kCGMouseButtonLeft);
    CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, a);
    CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile the script:

```
$ gcc -o click click.m -framework ApplicationServices -framework Foundation
```

Run the executable:

```
$ ./click -x 10 -y 20
```

The above execution works, but when I move the file to another folder, the script runs, but the click is not performed anymore:

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir testfolder
$ mv click ~/testfolder
$ cd ~/testfolder
$ ./click -x 10 -y 20
```

It does not work anymore. But if instead of moving the file to `testfolder` I move it to `/Applications` folder or leave it in the Desktop, it works.

Comment: How are you running them, and what happens when they're not in one of those folders?

Comment: A _file_ with its _executable bit set_ and in a _directory_ that is in the `PATH` can be executed just by its `filename`. If it's not in a _directory_ that is in the `PATH` it can be executed by its _fully qualified pathname_, e.g. /path/to/filename` or its _relative pathname_. e.g. `./filename` or `./path/to/filename` or `../path/to/filename`. **Are you following these rules?**

Comment: It's an okay question, but you'll probably want to provide very specific details. The first sentence doesn't seem right either; seems like unusual behaviour because neither of those directories are traditionally in the default `$PATH`. instead of just saying *Desktop or Applications folder*, refer to them by their full (absolute) paths. They will probably look something like `/Users/gcstr/Desktop/click` or `/Users/gcstr/Applications/click`. Also, check your current working directory with `pwd`. Alternatively you should be able to `cd` to the relevant directory to get what you want .

Comment: Thanks @voices, I added the steps to reproduce. The `$PATH` doesn't really matter because I'm running the executable from a relative path as you can see in the example above. I only find weird that the executable behaves differently on specific folders.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem here, the binary also works in `testfolder`

Comment: I too **cannot** reproduce the problem here, the binary also works in any directory I put it in and tested on HFS+, APFS and FAT32 formatted  volumes. The Apple menu is opened every time I run `./click -x 10 -y 20` from every directory I copied it to. Not that I think it should make any difference, but what version of **macOS** are you running?

Comment: Catalina 10.15.1

Comment: Is there any kind of error handling you could add to see whether one of the functions returns an error?

Comment: I just tested under **macOS Catalina** 10.15.1 and got all the same results as under **macOS High Sierra**, it works as mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: How long since your last reboot? If you reboot, does the issue persist?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I just tried rebooting and the results are the same. I find it very weird that it is not reproducible in other computers, I just tested on another mac and wasn't able as well to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I rewrote the script in swift and compiled with `swiftc`. Now the executable works on every folder.

Comment: That is interesting! I wonder if it's an issue isolated in the current user account or if it's reproducible from a different user account? Anyway, you have a workaround with swift and I'd love to see the code.